# Learning PHP arrays and switch

Tags: php, arrays

My instructions are commented out and I am trying to code as outlined.

I feel like I passed off the variable into intval wrong, incorrectly implemented the switch method, and checking if not null poorly.

```html
<?php
    // $IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX refers to the provided images subdirectory...
$IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX = 'images/';

    // images/globals.php defines two arrays representative of the images
    // that can be loaded...
require_once($IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX.'globals.php');

    // By default assume no image was selected so:
    //   a) the image file ($IMAGE) is set to null
    //   b) the image file's MIME type is set to null...
$IMAGE = null;
$IMAGE_MIME = null;

    // pic.php will be accessed using URL parameters, e.g., pic.php?i=2.
    // Per what was demonstrated in class obtain the GET parameter's
    // key-value pages using the global array $_GET. The parameters are
    // as follows:
    //   a) 'i' is an image number (e.g., 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.)
    //   b) 'purpose' is either 'g' or 'a'
    //
    // So:
    //   * if purpose=g then look up the image file to use in the $LETTERS
    //     array where i=<INTEGER> is the index into $LETTTERS
    //   * if purpose=a then look up the image file to use in the $NUMBERS
    //     array where i=<INTEGER> is the index into $NUMBERS
    //
    // Sample (partial) URLs:
    //   * pic.php?i=3&purpose=g
    //   * pic.php?purpose=a&i=2
    //
    // Because an invalid index can be passed, before accessing the array
    // do the following:
    //   1) Obtain the $_GET for 'i', e.g., $_GET['i'].
$_GET['i'];
    //   2) Pass (1) into PHP's intval(). This will ensure it is an int.
    //      NOTE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
intval ($i);
    //   3) Obtain the $_GET for 'purpose'.
$_GET['purpose'];
    //   4) Use a switch statement or a suitable equivalent on (3).
    //      4a) If (4) matches 'a' then call array_key_exists() on $NUMBERS
    //          with the value obtained in (2) as the index. If the key exists
    //          set $IMAGE to the concatenation of $IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX, '/', and 
    //          the string at index in $NUMBERS.
    //      4b) If (4) matches 'g' then call array_key_exists() on $LETTERS
    //          with the value obtained in (2) as the index. If the key exists
    //          set $IMAGE to the concatenation of $IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX, '/', and 
    //          the string at index in $LETTERS.
    //      NOTE: In PHP the '.' operator is string concatenation.
switch (purpose){
    case a:
    if (array_key_exists('i', $NUMBERS)) {
    $IMAGE .= $IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX . '/'. $NUMBERS;
    }
    case g:
    if (array_key_exists('i', $LETTERS)) {
    $IMAGE .= $IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX . '/'. $LETTERS;
    }
}
    //   5) Now that a possible $IMAGE has been set (NOTE: it still might be null),
    //      determine the image's MIME type. Instead of hard-coding it, you will
    //      use PHP's finfo object to determine the MIME type of the file.
    //      Internally the finfo object determines the MIME type using magic strings
    //      (i.e., in the way the 'file' command does this from the command line).
    //      Determine the MIME type as follows:
    //      5a) If $IMAGE is NOT null:
if (!empty($IMAGE)) {
    $fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $result = $fi->file($IMAGE);
        if (!empty($result)) {
        $IMAGE_MIME=$result;
        }
}
    //        5b) $fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    //            $result = $fi->file($IMAGE); // Returns MIME type unless an error occurred
    //        5c) If $result is not an error, set $IMAGE_MIME to $result.
    //    6) If $IMAGE and $IMAGE_MIME are both NOT null, then output the image with:
    //         header('Content-Type: '.$IMAGE_MIME);
    //         @readfile($IMAGE);
    //         exit;
if (!empty($IMAGE) && !empty($IMAGE_MIME)) {
    header('Content-Type: '.$IMAGE_MIME);
    @readfile($IMAGE);
    exit;
    }
    //    7) Otherwise, generate an HTTP 404 File Not Found response and page with:
    //         http_response_code(404);
    //         echo <<<ZZEOF
    //         <!DOCTYPE html>
    //         <html>
    //           <head><title>2017W 03-60-334 Assignment 2: 404 File Not Found</title></head>
    //           <body><h1>404 File Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource could not be found.</p></body>
    //         </html>
    //         ZZEOF;
    //         exit(0);
 ?>
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to accomplish? Are you currently getting an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: I don't get any sort of error. But my code is not working, the images are not loading. I assume its my arrays portion.

Comment: You aren't checking for errors. `switch (purpose){` is an error, `case a:` is an error.. `$_GET['purpose'];` does nothing, `intval ($i);` does nothing, `$_GET['i'];` does nothing. You need to be assigning, and enable error reporting and/or check your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the simple stuff:

declare variable `i` like this:

```
$i=intval($_GET["i"]);
```

declare variable `purpose` like this:

```
$purpose=$_GET["purpose"];
```

this assumes you will have a querystring like `?i=1&purpose=a` at the end of your page's url

the, now, declared variables may be accessed using their $-prefixed name.
case strings must be single or double quoted

```
switch($purpose){
    case "a":
```

if `NUMBERS` and `LETTERS` are arrays, then `array_key_exists` is fine to use.
if you are searching for a key that has the value of variable `i`, then use `$i` like this:

```
if(array_key_exists($i,$NUMBERS)){
```

Now, you have already declared `$IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX = 'images/';`at the beginning of your code.

So, `$IMAGE .= $IMAGE_DIR_PREFIX . '/'` will be the prefix value then `//` which will be problematic.

then you try to concatenate `$IMAGE` with `$NUMBERS`, but if `NUMBERS` is an array, then you cannot access its values this way.  Rather, use something like:

```
$NUMBERS[$i];
```

The same advice holds true for `$LETTERS`.

Typically after each case statement, you use `break;` so that `switch` doesn't continue looking for other matches.  If you want to look for more matches, that is okay, but I don't think you do this time.

Just for your information, variables in php don't have to be ALL CAPS.

I'll stop there.
Please consider all of my advice.
Read as much as you can from online PHP manuals.
Always check your error logs.
Then isolate your problems.
Then read the manual again.
Then try yourself.
Then check your error logs.
... you get my point.

Comment: @Saterial I am not sure I can solve the question as it has too many issues, but if you find my answer useful please upvote it.